# Postgres, CREATE AGGREGATE, accessing index and row count inside aggregate function for [non]oxford comma text

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregates

The goal is a custom aggregate function made with [CREATE AGGREGATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html) called `string_agg_oxford`; it is an aggregate function that works similar to `string_agg` except it is smart enough to know how many items it is aggregating so that it can place "and" in front of the last item.

So where `string_agg(items, ', ')` would return `"item1, item2, item3"`, `string_agg_oxford(items)` will return `"item1, item2, and item3"`.

My failed attempt starts with a type for our accumulator that includes the total number of rows and the index for the current row:

```sql
CREATE TYPE oxford_accumulator as (
  row_count numeric,
  i numeric,
  acc text
);
```

Now we need our accumulator function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oxford_acc (acc oxford_accumulator, curr text)
  RETURNS oxford_accumulator
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS $$
BEGIN
  IF acc.i + 1 = acc.row_count THEN
    RETURN (acc.row_count, acc.i + 1, acc.acc || curr);
  END IF;

  IF (acc.i + 2 = acc.row_count) AND (acc.row_count = 2)  THEN
    RETURN (acc.row_count, acc.i + 1, acc.acc || curr || ' and ');
  END IF;

  IF (i + 2 = acc.row_count) THEN
    RETURN (acc.row_count, acc.i + 1, acc.acc || curr || ', and ');
  END IF;

  RETURN (acc.row_count, acc.i + 1, acc.acc || curr || ', ');
END;
$$;
```

because the accumulator has swallowed up the total count and the index we have to release this information when the accumulator is finished with an `ffunc`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oxford_final (acc oxford_accumulator)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN acc.acc;
END;
$$;
```

My idea falls apart here where we need to wire it all up because there does not seem to be a way to parametrize the total row count... so fail.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE string_agg_oxford (text, row_count numeric) (
  INITCOND = (row_count, 0, ''),
    --         ^^^ fail
  STYPE = oxford_accumulator,
  SFUNC = oxford_acc,
  FINALFUNC = oxford_final
);
```

I know something similar can be achieved with a regular function, but I'm not ready to give up yet if there's a way to do this as an aggregator that could be used in a select statement like `SELECT string_agg_oxford(clients.full_name) FROM matters GROUP BY matters.matter_id;`

Comment: [From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html) "***initial_condition** The initial setting for the state value. This must be a string constant in the form accepted for the data type state_data_type*". As it has to be a string _constant_ I don't see how you can provide a dynamic value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Initial condition must be "a string constant in the form accepted for the data type state_data_type" so no way to pass a dynamic value. Credit to @a_horse_with_no_name
2. For efficiency reasons, it would be easier to "peel the last value out of the accumulator." Credit to @jjanes.
3. Lets use a unique separator to alleviate any issues matching on ", " because that is fairly common - so we'll use a unique separator and then replace those in the ffunc as is appropriate.
4. Postgres does not support having capture groups within its lookahead assertions, so instead of a fancy regular expression to find the last occurrence of our unique separator, we will reverse the string and tackle things upside down.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oxford_acc (acc text, curr text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN acc || curr || '@$@$';
  --                     ^^^ unique separator, can be anything unique
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oxford_final (acc text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS $$
DECLARE
    my_result text;
    my_counter numeric;
BEGIN
    SELECT left(acc, -4) INTO my_result;
    -- ^^^ removes the last separator
    SELECT count(*) FROM regexp_matches(my_result, '@\$@\$', 'g') INTO my_counter;
    
    IF my_counter = 0 THEN
      RETURN my_result;
    END IF;
    
    IF my_counter = 1 THEN
      RETURN regexp_replace(my_result, '@\$@\$', ' and ');
    END IF;
    
    SELECT reverse(my_result) INTO my_result;
    
    SELECT regexp_replace(my_result, '\$@\$@', ' dna ,') INTO my_result;
    
    SELECT reverse(my_result) INTO my_result;
    
    RETURN regexp_replace(
      my_result, 
      '@\$@\$',
      ', ',
      'g'
    );
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE oxford_agg (text) (
  INITCOND = '',
  STYPE = text,
  SFUNC = oxford_acc,
  FINALFUNC = oxford_final
);
```

Suggestions for improvements welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Right, you don't know you are done until you are done.  You would have to make two passes over the data, one to get the count and the other to construct the string.  That wouldn't be very efficient, and there is no obvious way to make PostgreSQL do it that way that could be used as a simple aggregate.  I think you could use a window function to get the total count, then an aggregate which takes two arguments (string and total count), but I think you would need to write that part in an "outer query", otherwise it wouldn't have access to the total count.

The straightfoward way to do this would be to use the same accumulator and transition function as `string_agg(x, ', ')`, but have your finalizer function just peel the last value out of the accumulator, and tack it back on with an ', and '.

Or you could define an accumulator with `(acc text, prev text)` and have the transition function tack the prev into acc (if prev isn't null) then store its current value into prev.  Then have the finalizer tack the final prev into acc with the ', and ' separator.